# How to fetch any subreddit images, including adult ones? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, reddit

I found this code and tried to test it, it doesn’t reply with anything.

Could somebody try fix it or show me another way of getting subreddit’s post pictures (memes, nsfw)?
I’m sure that most people have same question, thanks.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "TDankmeme",
    run : async (client, message, args) => {
            try {
                const { body } = await snekfetch
                    .get('https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes.json?sort=top&t=week')
                    .query({ limit: 800 });
                const allowed = message.channel.nsfw ? body.data.children : body.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.over_18);
                if (!allowed.length) return message.channel.send('It seems we are out of fresh memes!, Try again later.');
                const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)
                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(0x00A2E8)
                .setTitle(allowed[randomnumber].data.title)
                .setDescription("Posted by: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.author)
                .setImage(allowed[randomnumber].data.url)
                .addField("Other info:", "Up votes: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.ups + " / Comments: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.num_comments)
                .setFooter("Memes provided by r/dankmemes")
                message.channel.send(embed)
            } catch (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: snekfetch is deprecated. Use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), or a designated package that makes this easier, like [reddit-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reddit-fetch).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `random-reddit` for my bot. and its working good.

Here's a basic setup:

```js
const reddit = require('@elchologamer/random-reddit');

let options = {
   imageOnly: true,
   allowNSFW: true
};

reddit.getPost('memes', options).then(post => { //Make sure to change 'memes' with whatever subreddit you want

   var title = post.title
   var content = post.text
   var postURL = post.permalink
   var postAuthor = post.author
   var upvotes = post.upvotes
   var downvotes = post.downvots
}
```

you can use the variables or use `console.log(post)` to get the full data.

the npm package and documentation can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elchologamer/random-reddit)